# Set text in table cell by clicking a button in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, oracle-apex

I have a problem I wrote a code I have a table and I want to set text to one of my cell in table on button click:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function navratna()
{
var y=document.getElementById("navrat");
y.value="ahoj";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td height="20" width="100" id="navrat">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="pokus" onclick="navratna()"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Please can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also use `innerText`:

```
function navratna()
{
var y=document.getElementById("navrat");
y.innerText="ahoj";
}
<body>
    <table border="1">
<tr>
<td height="20" width="100" id="navrat">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<input

 type="button" value="pokus" onclick="navratna()"/>
</body>
```

Answer (score 10):

`value` is a property of form elements only. You have to use [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.innerHTML):

```
function navratna()
{
    var y = document.getElementById("navrat");
    y.innerHTML = "ahoj";
}
```

There are also various other attributes to set only text (which would be the most appropriate in your situation), but they differ from browser to browser. `innerHTML` is the best cross-browser way.

Answer (score 2):

Use `innerHTML` instead of `value`.

```
function navratna()
{
  var y = document.getElementById("navrat");
  y.innerHTML = "ahoj";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function navratna()
{
    var y=document.getElementById("navrat");
    y.innerHTML="ahoj";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use `innerHTML`

```
y.innerHTML ="ahoj";
```